# How to compute component values for current-controlled 555-based oscillator?

Tags: 555, constant-current

I am building a project where I plan to have a current controlled oscillator based on a 555.  The oscillator is controlled using current source I1 (a current mirror) charging capacitor C2 in lieu of the usual charging resistor.  The current provided by I1 varies depending on some other parts of the circuitry and is supposed to affect the frequency of oscillation at the 555's output.

My questions are:

- Is this circuit correct and suitable for building a current controlled oscillator?  I am also interested in better circuits if any.
- How can I compute the frequency and duty cycle depending on the current delivered by I1 and the values of R1 and C2?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWBC6X.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: How did you design this without knowing how the a 555 timer work? Seems to me you skipped a few steps. Because that would answer your question right there.

Comment: @DKNguyen I do know how a 555 works.  I expect that in the charge cycle I1 charges C2 until the trigger is met.  Then, the discharge cycle discharges C2 through R1 until the threshold voltage is met, with the current from I1 being wasted.  I just don't know enough electronics to feel confident calculating the resulting frequencies.

Comment: CV=IT would be used for the current source charging the cap. Discharge seems like it might have issues because there is no guarantee that the R1 overpowers the current source. A better circuit is the typical one with no current source because the 555 wasn't ever designed to be used with current sources and was designed to be used easily with voltage sources.

Comment: @DKNguyen In my use case I'm confident it does (the current source delivers less than 300 µA and I can select a sufficiently small resistor to have the discharge work out).

Comment: Do you have any real specs or expectations for tolerance, range ,stability?

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Yes.  V1 delivers 3.3V, I1 is in the range from 50 µA to 300 µA and I want an output frequency in the range of 2 kHz to 10 kHz (needs not correspond to the input current range given).  The duty cycle doesn't really matter.  It is ok if the frequency drifts slightly with temperature or supply voltage.  It also does not need to be super precise.

Comment: I wonder if I could discharge over an inductor instead of a resistor to avoid the overpowering problem DKNguyen mentioned.

Comment: You don't need a 555 to do this nor a current source when you have hysteresis when Ic=CdV/dt and dV hysteresis is < 30% in the linear range

Comment: The discharge scenario isn't very convenient. You basically have to solve for the circuit formed by the current source, discharge pin transistor, R1, and the cap. I don't see a napkin calculation for it.

Comment: @DKNguyen Is it easier to solve if I use a CMOS part (e.g. a TLC555)?

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 This might be some kind of XY problem.  I am trying to drive an oscillator according to the current consumption of some circuitry.  I plan to do this by mirroring the current and then using the mirrored current as shown in the question.  I'm not sure how to achieve this by some other way.

Comment: No it isn't easier. The pin transistor isn't the problem (it just introduces a flat voltage drop which is easy to handle). It's that the current source affects the R1 voltage so both cap and current source influence the discharge, and for some values can charge up the cap or never let the cap voltage fall low enough. It's messy.

Comment: You know what? Place R1 in series with the C2 so that the threshold pin is between R1 and C2 and the discharge pin is between R1 and I1. Then I1 will be unaffected and discharge will short to ground both R1 and current source to gnd so they do not influence each other during discharge. Then only I1 will influence the charge and only R1 will influence the discharge.

Comment: @DKNguyen The purpose of R1 is to set the duration of the discharge cycle and to avoid overloading the discharge transistor (datasheet for the TLC555 gives a maximum rating of 150 mA, so 22Ω minimum for the discharge resistor).  Neither objective is achieved unless R1 is in the discharge path.  And I don't need it in the charge path.

Comment: Think about it. By placing R1 between the discharge and threshold pins, when the discharge pin shorts to ground I1 won't flow through R1. It is in the charge path, but I1 is a current source so will be unaffected.

Comment: @DKNguyen Again: then the maximum current flow rating for the 555 chip will be exceeded which I want to avoid.  And if it's not in the discharge path I can completely get rid of it since that's the only place it is needed.  So not sure why you want to place it there.

Comment: And how exactly do you expect a 300uA current source to overload a transistor that can handle 150mA? And R1 would be in both the charge and discharge path, but because I1 is a current source it ignores it.

Comment: @DKNguyen The discharge current of the capacitor might, not the current source.  In the discharge cycle the capacitor is discharged  to ground through R1.  Remove R1 and the current should be very large.

Comment: Go back and read my description of where to move R1. I think you're misinterpreting something. 4 posts up and 6 posts up from this one. Same thing described in two different ways.

Comment: @DKNguyen Ah I misread your explanation (seems like you edited your comment) as wanting to place it somewhere outside of the discharge path.  Placing it between threshold and discharge on the vertical line seems like a good idea.  If you can compute the frequency and duty cycle with that circuit I think that would answer my question.

Comment: It seems to me that you're trying to make a current-to-frequency converter. It would help to know what application this would fit in, because it's not necessarily the best solution. For example, most MCUs with a built-in comparator can do the job of a 555 in this application without any external components but the capacitor itself. Even without a built-in comparator they still can do it, just with less precision.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica Yes, I am trying to make a current to frequency converter.  I have some digital circuitry and I want to measure how much current flows through it and then drive an oscillator depending on the amount of current that flew.  I would like to not use a micro controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move R1 here so that I1 does not flow through R1 (and potentially C1 depending on chosen values)and influence the discharge.

[image]

Then from \$Q=CV\$ and \$Q=IT\$ you can produce \$CV=IT\$ which becomes:

\$t_{\textit{charge}} = \frac{C_2V_{2/3}}{I_1}\$

\$t_{\textit{discharge}} = R_1 C_2 \$ can be used for the discharge time as normal.

From these two times you can get frequency and duty cycle:

\$\textit{Duty} = \frac{t_{\textit{charge}}}{t_{\textit{charge}}+t_{\textit{discharge}}}\$

\$f = \frac{1}{t_{\textit{charge}}+t_{\textit{discharge}}}\$